# Are all hosted jQuery the same?

Tags: jquery

jQuery has many hosts, like Google and Microsoft. Do the jQuery libraries hosted by different companies vary? Or, they are the same for the same version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same for each version. You can pick which one you like.

When importing them to your website it's a good idea to go for the minified versions.

The only difference may be found in the initial comment before the library starts (sourceMappingURL) but as far as the library itself it is identical.

I'd recommend using Google's hosted jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since they usually have decreased latency and better caching..